# How to filter the data that edit and it should display the data that selected to edit in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
const arr = [
 'code1',
 'code2',
 'code3',
 'code4',
 'code5'
];


  const data = [ 
{
device: 'code1'
}, {
device: 'code2'
} ];

  const code = data.map((x: any) => x.device);

 const sample = arr.filter((x: any) => code.indexOf(x) < 0);
```

there's a two data that already created.
which is the device code1 and code2.

what I'm trying to do is. on my side there's a edit.

example i have a list code1 to code 5

then I have two data which is the code1 and code 2.

when I try to edit the data has code 1.

on my list it should display the code1 and the code2 will not displayed.

it should be like this when I try to edit the code1:

```
[
'code1',
'code3',
'code4',
'code5'
]
```

Comment: Can you edit more than one at once? Otherwise I'd just say deal with it with `activeIndex`

Comment: @Misiur the problem is, when I try to edit the ```code1``` it doesn't display on my list. the output is ```['code3','code4','code5']```. it should be ```['code1','code3','code4','code5']```. the code2 will not display

Comment: @Misiur here's the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwzboj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Add non constant string to tell what you are currently editing.  Also you may need to add exception handing to throw and error if what you are currently editing isn't a viable code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public currentEdit: string = 'code1';

  ngOnInit() {
    const arr = [
      'code1',
      'code2',
      'code3',
      'code4',
      'code5'
    ];

const data = [ 
  {
  device: 'code1'
  }, 
  {
  device: 'code2'
  } 
];

const code = data.map((x: any) => x.device);

const sample = arr.filter((x: any) => code.indexOf(x) < 0 || x === this.currentEdit);
console.log(sample);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you know which one to be edited, why cant u use that information and filter out the arr.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    const arr = [
      'code1',
      'code2',
      'code3',
      'code4',
      'code5'
    ];


    const data = [ 
      {
      device: 'code1'
      }, 
      {
      device: 'code2'
      } 
    ];
    const toBeEdited = "code1";
    let code = data.map((x: any) => x.device);
    code = code.filter((data)=>(data!=toBeEdited))[0];
    const sample = arr.filter((x: any) => code.indexOf(x) < 0);
    console.log(sample);
  }
}
```

`